# com.google.common.util.concurrent .UncheckedExecutionException: org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException

Tags: java, maven, cxf, guava

In my build.gradle file i am using Guava 19.0 and cxf-rt-rs-client 3.4.4 jar, but while deploying the project, i am getting the below error:

> ["Exception in thread "main" com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.common.util.ASMHelperImpl.", "\tat com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2199)", "\tat com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3932)", "\tat com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3936)", "\tat com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4806)", "\tat com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4812)", "\tat com.cloudera.api.ClouderaManagerClientBuilder.build(ClouderaManagerClientBuilder.java:272)", "\tat com.cloudera.api.ClouderaManagerClientBuilder.build(ClouderaManagerClientBuilder.java:252)", "\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.service.CmService.connect(CmService.java:395)", "\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.action.CmCommand.executeCommand(CmCommand.java:95)", "\tat com.cisco.ivsg.cm.client.action.CmCommand.main(CmCommand.java:83)", "Caused by: org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.common.util.ASMHelperImpl.", "\tat org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.tryClass(Extension.java:183)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.getClassObject(Extension.java:199)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.activateAllByType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:139)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.(ExtensionManagerBus.java:145)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.(ExtensionManagerBus.java:151)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusFactory.createBus(CXFBusFactory.java:40)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusFactory.createBus(CXFBusFactory.java:36)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusFactory.createBus(CXFBusFactory.java:32)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:107)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.createThreadBus(BusFactory.java:243)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:227)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:214)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServiceFactoryBean.getBus(JAXRSServiceFactoryBean.java:69)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServiceFactoryBean.createResourceInfo(JAXRSServiceFactoryBean.java:202)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServiceFactoryBean.setResourceClass(JAXRSServiceFactoryBean.java:148)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.setServiceClass(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:171)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.setResourceClass(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:162)", "\tat com.cloudera.api.ClouderaManagerClientBuilder$1.load(ClouderaManagerClientBuilder.java:103)", "\tat com.cloudera.api.ClouderaManagerClientBuilder$1.load(ClouderaManagerClientBuilder.java:99)", "\tat com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3522)", "\tat com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2315)", "\tat com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2278)", "\tat com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2193)", "\t... 9 more", "Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class", "\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)", "\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)", "\tat java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)", "\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)", "\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)", "\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)", "\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)", "\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)", "\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)", "\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)", "\tat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)", "\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)", "\tat org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.tryClass(Extension.java:164)", "\t... 31 more"]

Dependencies in build file:

```
`compile group: 'com.cloudera.api', name: 'cloudera-manager-api', version:'6.3.0'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version:'1.7.21'
    compile group: 'com.github.stefanbirkner', name: 'system-rules', version:'1.3.0'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'eclipselink', version:'2.4.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-transports-http', version:'2.7.7'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version:'20140107'

    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version:'1.7.30'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.12'
    compile files('src/resources/javamail-4.0.jar')
    compile(group: 'commonlibs', name: 'aes128-encryption', version: '1.1.3')
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.13'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.10.3'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.13.0'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-base', version: '2.10.3'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-json-provider', version: '2.10.3'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-jaxb-annotations', version: '2.10.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-rs-client', version: '3.4.4'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '19.0'
```

Can you please suggest on what shall i do further, as i have already tried keeping cxf 3.4.2 and guava 30-jre, guava-15.0, but none of them worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: dependencies provided